# Help on Finding More Information on German Connotation

Tags: connotation

I have been trying for weeks to find information on German Connotation (the difference in *feeling* between synonyms, eg. *evil* vs *benevolent*) and have been able to find almost nothing.

Now it could just be that I'm obsessing over this, but I really want to be able to understand the subtle differences between German words, because I feel like I'm just translating American thoughts into the German language and not really *thinking* like and thus speaking like a German.

**Update:**
Thank you for all the comments, sorry if this question was a bit confusing, I was very tired at the time lol. I feel like I'm just really bad at looking for things because I didn't even consider using a Thesaurus. lol rip. But thank you for all the comments!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Evil and benevolent are not synonyms. You'll probably get a better feeling for words by reading a lot or watching movies (preferably not American ones which could have problematic translations). Ask specific questions here.

Comment: One difference that comes to my mind is that Americans tend to exaggerate much more. For example, it's common to say "I love (or hate) this food". In German,"lieben" and "hassen" are usually too strong and you'd probably hear "(nicht) mögen" instead. Is this the kind of explanations you're looking for?

Comment: You could simply start to read *not only the first* translation from the dictionary. Most words translate into several meanings, often within significant bandwidth - This will give you already quite some insights into connotations - **and you probably meant to write *malevolent***

Comment: You are looking for the german equivalent of a thesaurus, right? It's called **Synonymwörterbuch**.

Comment: You mean words like "grinsen". In German, that has a slightly insincere or negative connotation (more like "smirk", i.e. "böse, spöttisch oder auch dümmlich lächeln"), while in English, it doesn't. There, it just means to smile broadly. Is that an example of what you mean?

Comment: FWIW, there is no real list of the differences in connotation between German and English words, as far as I know. You'll just have to look them up one by one, I'm afraid. I personally could use one for the opposite direction. Being a foreigner (I'm Dutch), I have had similar problems, with both languages. <g>

Answer (score 2):

You can't learn connotation from a dictionary. While technically the necessary information is in there, it's almost impossible to acquire in that format.

To choose synonyms ideomatically, the thing to do is consume  a lot of spoken or written German and encounter them repeatedly in different contexts. Your mind will begin to associate e.g. "pingelig" with a derogatory connotation and "sorgfältig" with an appreciative one, and literally before you know it, you will begin to form those associations yourself.

Comment: Mir scheint Du redest von den feineren Unterschieden der Bedeutung, nicht von Nebenbedeutungen. Wobei der Unterschied von sorgfältig und pingelig eher ein grober ist.

Answer (score 2):

Commenters who said that the most important thing is 'consuming' a lot of German language in practical use (reading books, watching movies, listening to good radio stations, watching clips on video sharing platforms etc.) are completely right. It is only by diving into the language that you will become aware of all the connotations going with words and phrases. However, as this will not help you on the short run, may I suggest the obvious:

**You should buy a good defining dictionary** (Bedeutungswörterbuch).

I would recommend

> Duden Deutsches Universalwörterbuch

In the most recent edition (8. Auflage, 2120 pages) this has about 190,000 lemmata. (They say it has 500,000 words, but that's a different way of counting.) You get this as a book for approximately 50 euros, or 30 as pdf (plus optional computer application / database programme). Or if you are happy with the 6. edition (which will absolutely do in most cases), you get the pdf currently for 16 euros. But be aware that a book is much more convenient than a pdf (unless you have to travel with it).

Another good option, but smaller (and cheaper):

> Wahrig. Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache.

Available as a book for 20 euros.

My personal favorite is

> Duden Deutsches Universalwörterbuch, 2. Auflage, 1989. 1816 Seiten. 120,000 lemmata.

This you will get only from second-hand sources, but then for as little as 5 euros or so, plus shipping. Although of course it has only words that were in use pre-1989 and so a lot of computing and youth slang is not included, I like it for various reasons, one of them being that it fully relies on the traditional spelling rules, so I can look up how things were spelled before the Ministers of Education in Germany tried to impose controverse new spelling rules in 1996, and all the subsequent corrections to that (but that's a different discussion).

Don't buy one of the smaller dictionaries (issued also by the same publishers). For your purpose, you need the large ones. They provide you with the most nuances in meaning, and with many good examples for real-life use of the words.

As an example, here is what the latest Duden Universalwörterbuch edition has for your *übel* (note that explanation of meaning is set in italics, examples for the use of the word in various typical phrases is set in regular letters):

> **übel** 〈Adj.; übler, übelste〉 [mhd. übel, ubel, ahd.
>   ubil]: **1.** *ein unangenehmes Gefühl hervorrufend;
>   dem Empfinden sehr unangenehm, zuwider;
>   mit Widerwillen wahrgenommen*: übler
>   Fusel*; ü. schmecken; eine ü. riechende Flüssigkeit;
>   nicht ü. (ugs.; *eigentlich recht gut*). **2.** *nicht
>   so, wie es dem Wunsch, der Absicht entsprochen
>   hätte; sich zum Nachteil entwickelnd; mit Widrigkeiten,
>   Beschwernissen verbunden*: übles
>   Wetter; eine üble Situation; das kann ü. ausgehen;
>   ein ü. beleumundeter, ü. beleumdeter Zeitgenosse;
>   ein ü. gesinnter (*nicht wohlwollend
>   gesinnter*) Nachbar; das ist ihr ü. bekommen; er
>   hat dies ü. vermerkt (*war ärgerlich, böse darüber*);
>   jmdm. etw. ü. nehmen (*verübeln, mit Verärgerung
>   od. gekränkt aufnehmen*); er hat deine
>   Bemerkung sehr, ernstlich ü. genommen; sie ist
>   wirklich ü. dran (*befindet sich in einer misslichen
>   Lage*); jmdm. ü. mitspielen. **3.** *Unbehaglichkeit,
>   Unwohlsein ausdrückend; nicht heiter
>   u. angenehm*: eine üble Laune; ein ü. gelaunter
>   Kollege; jmdm. ist, wird ü. (*jmd. hat das Gefühl,
>   sich übergeben zu müssen*). **4.** **a)** (*in Bezug auf
>   sittlich-moralische Werte) schlecht; sehr fragwürdig,
>   anrüchig*: ein übler Ruf; in üble Gesellschaft
>   geraten; eine üble Spelunke; **b)** (*dem
>   Grad nach) schlimm, arg*: jmdm. ü. mitspielen;
>   ü. zugerichtet werden.